# How to plot Gaussian shaped histogram in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a `df` named `s` with just one column:

```
size
20
28
38
42
42
42
44
124
176
192
194
216
228
316
318
2048
2714
2802
4128
4186
6910
9313
10816
16560
20704
34766
91022
```

and I am plotting a histogram for the same using

```
sns.distplot(s['size'], bins = len(s))
```

and it yields a result as follows:
[image]

I would like to know how can I make a few changes:

1. I would like to histogram to have a kind of gaussian look as follows: [Example of a Gaussian look](https://bespokeblog.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/histogram4.png) (this is just an example to show the kind of histogram I am expecting)
2. In the graph I plotted, the bins are not continuous, meaning there is a gap between 2 bins. I want to have no gaps between 2 bins while I am plotting them.

I would like to know how can these 2 tasks be achieved.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the `bins` argument to, say, 5, 8 or 10 and seeing what happens?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it still says the same

Comment: A histogram counts how many values of your dataset fall into each bin; your data is not distributed in a way that *even-width* bins could reproduce the "Gaussian look" you're after, since you have "many" small values but only "few" large ones. To get your look, you would have to create one *huge* bin for medium to large values, and then several smaller ones for the smaller values.

Comment: @Asmus a bin width inversely proportional to the frequency density will get to an uniform-like distribution I guess. Anyway, it's not clear if OP really wants an histogram or a plot of those values, looking at the accepted answer

Comment: The picture you link to is a *cumulative* histogram of a normally distributed variable. Given your data is not normally distributed at all, you probably just want a cumulative histogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to struggle getting the "Guassian look" you want given that this data is not normally distributed.

Using the `size` column as counts is the closest you'd be able to get to the "Guassian look" you linked (if this is at all how your data can be interpreted).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('seaborn')

data = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("""
20
28
38
42
42
42
44
124
176
192
194
216
228
316
318
2048
2714
2802
4128
4186
6910
9313
10816
16560
20704
34766
91022
"""), names=['size'], header=None)

plt.bar(range(data['size'].size), data['size'], width=1)
plt.xlabel('bin')
plt.ylabel('size')
```

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help (if only to an extent!)